# requests are not sent from the server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't know how to explain it correctly.
In general, I can't make a request to my server from the project using: `axios, needle, fetch`, it doesn't even send the request, it just gives out `data: ''I don't know how to fix it, sorry I don't even know how to explain it to you
There is no request on the server side.

But if I start using third-party programs like insomnia and stuff like that.
It sends and works. Maybe someone has encountered this problem
standart request:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/params..') // return data: ''
```

Comment: what does your browsers console and network tab show?

Comment: @tkausl, I have POST requests. It shows the usual axios settings structure. But if, I send a request through insomnia. Everything arrives and there is a response. But this way it only shows its settings outside the request.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.